# Clear values in number input in React

Tags: reactjs, input

I have two radio buttons, under each there are two number inputs. The goal is to clear the values that belong to deselected radio immediately on selecting the other radio.
I tried to resolve it by adding the ternary operator to defaultValue:

```
defaultValue={props.xxx ? props.yyy.toString() : ''}
```

But this works only when I refresh the page after selecting the radio, which isn't what I need. What is the way to clear the fields immediately when I select the other radio? I have read all similar questions here, but nothing helped in my situation.

The code is like this:

```
<Input
type="radio"
id="radio1"
label=""
name="radio"
onChange={() => onSomeChange(AbC, true)}
defaultChecked={props.aaa === true}
/>
            
<div className={cx({hidden: props.ooo})}>
{props.xxx === AbC && (
<div>
<Input 
type="number"
id="min-number"
name="min-max1"
label=""
defaultValue={props.xxx ? props.yyy.toString() : ''}
onBlur={(e) => onOtherChange(true, inputValue(e.target.value))}
/>
        
<Input
type="number"
id="max-number"
name="min-max1"
label=""
defaultValue={props.xxx ? props.yyy.toString() : ''}
onBlur={(e) => onOtherChange(false, inputValue(e.target.value))}
/>
</div>
)}
            
<Input
type="radio"
id="radio2"
label=""
name="radio"
onChange={() => onSomeChange(AbC, true)}
defaultChecked={props.aaa === true}
/>
            
<div className={cx({hidden: !props.ooo})}>
{props.xxx === AbC && (
<div>
<Input
type="number"
id="min-number2"
name="min-max2"
label=""
defaultValue={props.xxx ? props.yyy.toString() : ''}
onBlur={(e) => onOtherChange(true, inputValue(e.target.value))}
/>
<Input
type="number"
id="min-number2"
name="min-max2"
label=""
defaultValue={props.xxx ? props.yyy.toString() : ''}
onBlur={(e) => onOtherChange(false, inputValue(e.target.value))}
/>
</div>
)}
```

Comment: Any way you could better format this code. It's a bit tough to read.

Comment: Could you please also include a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example the shows how you are trying to clear any inputs?

Comment: Use state to hold all input fields value, then for the input fields whose values should be cleared, do a conditional check, then deselect it by resetting its value accordingly. Say `state.field1 = 1`, then `if(state.field1 === 1){ state.field2 = 0; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have only 2 radio inputs and 2 text inputs, you could handle it like this for 1 radio (you could do the same for other radios in your components).

```
const [radioValueA, setRadioValueA] = setState(false);
const [textValueA, setTextValueA] = setState(false);

onChangeRadio = (radioType, changedValue) => {
  if (radioType === 'A') {
    setTextValueA('');
    setRadioValueA(changedValue);
  } else {
    // handle other radio button - should be switch if there are many radio input
  }
}

// Radio A
<Input 
  type="radio"
  checked={radioValueA}
  onChange={event => onChangeRadio('A', event.target.value)}
/>
// Text A
<Input 
  type="text"
  checked={textValueA}
  onChange={event => setTextValueA(event.target.value)}
/>
```

The main ideas is you must control the input text value then set it to empty (clear) when radio button `onChange` event trigger